# How to send excel attachment while query output using sys.UTL_MAIL.send_attach_raw in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

In the below PL/SQL SP Cursor output store as HTML table and send as Excel file as attachment.

But I am getting the following error, even if I take `CLOB` datatype:

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: raw variable length too long
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_MAIL", line 654
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_MAIL", line 739

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_send_mail_with_attch (
    p_mode      char,
    p_message   VARCHAR2 := '.',
    p_subject   VARCHAR2 := '.',
    p_from      VARCHAR2 := 'ITTEAM'
) AS
    msg_from          VARCHAR2(50);
    msg_to            VARCHAR2(4000);
    message_to        VARCHAR2(50);
    mailhost          VARCHAR2(30);
    mailport          VARCHAR2(20);
    crlf              VARCHAR2(2) := chr(13)||  chr(10);
    msg_subject       VARCHAR2(250);
    tablehead         VARCHAR2(32767);
    message           VARCHAR2(32767);
    mainmsg           VARCHAR2(32767);
    v_errortext       VARCHAR2(200);
    v_errormsg        VARCHAR2(200) := ' ';
    v_error           VARCHAR2(2000) := ' ';
    mail_conn         utl_smtp.connection;
    attachment_text   clob;
    v_messageatt      clob;
    v_filedate        varchar2(100);

    CURSOR main_cursor IS
        select customer_id,customer_name, to_char(validity_date,'DD-MON-YYYY') validity_date
        FROM
            (select( trunc(validity_date) - trunc(sysdate) ) datediff,
                    a.* from table_name a WHERE lei_flag = 'Y'
            ) lei;

    main_cursor_var   main_cursor%rowtype;
begin
    SELECT a.smtpserver,a.smtpserverport,'' toaddress,'' fromaddress
    into mailhost,mailport,message_to,msg_from
    from emailsettingtable a
    WHERE ROWNUM < 2;

    msg_from := p_from;
    msg_to := '';
    IF p_mode = '89' THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('89');
        msg_to := message_to;
        msg_subject := 'CUSTOMER report';
        message := '<html><head></head>';
        message := message || '<body>';
        message := message || 'Dear Sir/Madam,<br>';
        message := message || 'Please find attached of Cutomer LEI Expiry<br>';
        message := message || '<table>';
        v_messageatt := '<html><head></head>';
        v_messageatt := v_messageatt || '<body><br>';
        v_messageatt := v_messageatt || '<table>';
        OPEN main_cursor;
        LOOP
            FETCH main_cursor INTO main_cursor_var;
            EXIT WHEN
                ( main_cursor%notfound );
            IF main_cursor%rowcount = 1 THEN
                v_messageatt := v_messageatt || '<tr><th>CUSTOMER ID</th><th>CUSTOMER NAME</th><th>VALIDITY DATE</th></tr>';
            END IF;
            v_messageatt := v_messageatt || '<tr>';
            v_messageatt := v_messageatt||  '<td>'|| main_cursor%rowcount||  '</td>';
            v_messageatt := v_messageatt||  '<td>'|| main_cursor_var.customer_id||  '</td>';
            v_messageatt := v_messageatt || '<td>'|| main_cursor_var.CUSTOMER_NAME||'</td>';
            v_messageatt := v_messageatt || '<td>'|| main_cursor_var.validity_date||'</td>';                   
            v_messageatt := v_messageatt || '</tr>';
            attachment_text := v_messageatt;
        END LOOP;

        CLOSE main_cursor;
        dbms_output.put_line('89');
        v_messageatt := v_messageatt || '</table>';
        message := message || '</table>';
        message := message||  '<br>'||  'Regards,<br>'||  'IT Team <br><br> ';
        message := message || '</body></html>';
        mainmsg := message;
        dbms_output.put_line(message);
    END IF;

    dbms_output.put_line('msg_subject-->' || msg_subject);
    dbms_output.put_line('MESSAGE-->' || message);
    IF p_mode = '89' THEN
       --msg_subject    := 'LERM Counterparty - Exposure Data Uploaded sucessfully ...';
        msg_to := msg_to || 'abc@gmail.com';
    END IF;

    select to_char(sysdate,'DD_MON_YYYYHH24:MI:SS') into v_filedate
    from dual;

 sys.utl_mail.send_attach_raw(
    sender => msg_from,
    recipients => msg_to,
    cc => '',
    bcc => '',
    subject => msg_subject,
    message => mainmsg,
    mime_type => 'text/html',
    priority => 1,
    attachment => utl_raw.cast_to_raw(attachment_text),
    att_inline => true,
    att_mime_type => 'text/plain; charset=us-ascii',
    att_filename => 'filename_'||  v_filedate||  '.xls',
    replyto => ''
);

    dbms_output.put_line('2');
    msg_to := '';
    dbms_output.put_line('Send Sucessfully ........');
EXCEPTION
    WHEN others THEN
        v_errortext := substr(sqlerrm,1,200);
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
END;
```

Comment: You can generate XLSX files from PL/SQL using the Alexandria PL/SQL library: https://github.com/mortenbra/alexandria-plsql-utils

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a HTML document (using `<table>..<tr>`, etc.) and convert  this simple to RAW. Creating a Excel file purely in PL/SQL is quite painful, perhaps you will find a solution here on SO. One solution is to call an external Java procedure which generates the Excel sheet.

In general you can format your e-mail as HTML with well known formation capabilities or you can attach a binary Excel file.

Attachment for `utl_mail.send_attach_raw` is limited to 32k, it also have some other limitation. I recommend to use `UTL_SMTP`, this package is more complex to use but it gives you much more flexibility. Have a look at [how to export data from log table to email body in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326026/how-to-export-data-from-log-table-to-email-body-in-oracle/44329605#44329605) to see a full featured example.

Comment: If Comment Line no 99 "attachment => utl_raw.cast_to_raw(attachment_text)"
My SP executed successfully
bu when i  uncomment  Line no 99,
I'm getting error 
Error report -
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line 45
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"