# Many receive SMTP email and others do not

Tags: oracle, plsql

Using PL/SQL code some people receive email and others do not. I have 10 in the list, 3 do not receive it.

```
v_from_name VARCHAR2(100):='ABCalert@lmnop.org';        
v_smtp_server VARCHAR2(255):='smtp.lmnop.org';    
conn := utl_smtp.open_connection(v_smtp_server,n_smtp_server_port);    
utl_smtp.rcpt(conn, 'abcabab@xyz.gov');   
utl_smtp.write_raw_data(conn, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('Cc: ' || 'abcabab@xyz.gov' || crlf));
```

I tried with the below as well but does not work.

```
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(conn, 'To: ' || '"Steve Smith" <ssmith@xyz.gov>' <|UTL_TCP.CRLF);
```

- People with @lmnop.org receive it - no issues
- People with @gmail.com receive it - no issues
- People with @veolia.com receive it - no issues
- People with @xyz.gov do not receive it.

Comment: Not sure how to edit format the post. : -(

Comment: Ask those 3 people to clean-up their mailboxes, it could be full.

Comment: One of those three joined recently, a couple months back, should not be a problem! is there a way to check if that is indeed a problem?

Comment: Umm.. Just try sending them email from your smartphone, maybe?

Comment: They are receiving other emails. I can forward the email notifications that I receive from the mailer. Problem seems to be with smtp ...

Comment: My knowledge on TCP, SMTP etc is poor but i  think there's no issue with Oracle or `UTL_SMTP` here  as your outgoing SMTP gateway seems to be working fine as it is able to send mails to few recipients. You have to check the configuration of  SMTP gateway which manages the inbound mail for those users.

Comment: Add `UTL_SMTP.RCPT(conn, 'ssmith@xyz.gov'); UTL_SMTP.RCPT(conn, 'abcabab@xyz.gov');`, i.e. for each recipient. The mail server may block the mail due to spam rule if `RCPT` does not match `To`, resp. `Cc` or `Bc` field. Check also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326026/how-to-export-data-from-log-table-to-email-body-in-oracle/44329605#44329605

Comment: I am sorry. I have to edit the last line of original post. I thought one person received it with email @ xyz . gov but now I understand that none with @xyz.gov email id receive the notifications.