# can I use stored procedure to send meeing request email?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I know I can write oracle stored procedure to send email. I wonder can I send meeting request email with it? Is it possible using the procedure create a .ics file and send as attachement. I checked online and can't find any sample code. Any help?Thanks.

Comment: [Email From Oracle PL/SQL - Emails with Attachments](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/email-from-oracle-plsql#attachment)

Comment: Even more generic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326026/how-to-export-data-from-log-table-to-email-body-in-oracle/44329605#44329605

Comment: open whichever email client you use, create a meeting and save that *.ics file on your desktop, open the file in your favourite text editor and try to understand the contents in the file. They look pretty straight forward to me. you can create a file like that in PL/SQL easily