# How to pad information into columns for email

Tags: oracle, plsql, smtp, gmail

I am trying send a email from an Oracle database with an SMTP function with Gmail.

The information is selected with a query in the database, so, for each column I set the space with `RPAD`. I make the message with this structure:

```
l_mailtext := l_mailtext || CHR(9) || LPAD(L_NUMBER, 6, '0') || CHR(9) ||
                  CHR(9) || CHR(9) || '  ' || I.CONTRACT_REF_NO || CHR(9) ||
                  RPAD(I.SPEI_TRACE_NO, 40, ' ') ||
                  RPAD(I.REMARKS, 30, CHR(32)) || 
                  rpad(I.ACTUAL_AMOUNT, 30, ' ') || 
                  rpad(I.PC_STATUS, 30, ' ') || CHR(10);
```

Doing the process, I checked the mail sent and the information shows the following; this is via Gmail in Google Chrome.

[image: Gmail in Google Chrome.]

I copy and paste the same information in a Notepad++ sheet and it shows me the correct layout:

[image: Notepad++].

So, I need the information looks like Notepad ++ in Gmail. I do not know if there is a ASCIIcharacter for padding information. Because information in "Amount" column disorganizes by Payment concept Column in Gmail message.

Comment: Gmail is just using a variable-width font; Notepad++ is using a monospaced font. Are you sending the email as plain text or as HTML/RTF? (As a side issue, you also need to look at the character set, to show the right character instead of ? in `CAMPI?A`, presumably that should be [`Ĩ`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0128/index.htm)?).

Comment: Hello, I am sending as a plain Text and it is not necessary show the right character (It is the ñ). It is possible take HTML tags for send a message from Oracle database and how can I make the function to send a message using HTML Structure?

Comment: Please edit your question to show us how you are sending the message now, so we can see if that can be adjusted or if you need a different approach.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326026/how-to-export-data-from-log-table-to-email-body-in-oracle/44329605#44329605

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data *is* padded correctly. You've demonstrated that in NP++. Gmail is displaying your email body in a proportional font, where each character is a different width. I figure, you have two options:

1. Send the email with a header of `Content-type: text/html` and make the body HTML (I *think* you can do this). You could probably wrap `<pre>` tags around your content, which tells the user agent to render it in a fixed-width font with spacing preserved.
2. You could send your content in a .txt attachment, which would likely open up in something like Notepad++, where it would be in a fixed-width font. If they have .txt attachments set to open in Wordpad, that won't be true.

Note that this doesn't really have to do with Gmail. This has to do with the mail client your recipient is using and how you are identifying your content. Today, it may be Gmail, tomorrow, they might switch to Outlook or Thunderbird.