# Create a text grid in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a grid like this

```
produce | price
________________
Apple   | $1.3
________________
Orange  | $ 2.6
```

The vertical borders are optional.

Right now this is what I have

```
stringBuilder := '';
for i in (select * from produces) loop
    stringBuilder := stringBuilder || ' ' || i.name || ' ' || i.price || chr(10);
end loop;
```

but the above query does not generate the correct format. What it creates is:

```
Apple $1.3 

Orange $1.6
```

Which has uneven alignment.

Comment: May I suggest that you use a reporting tool to handle this, such as a UI or maybe language like Java?  SQL is good at generating tables of data, not so much making them look good.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen we are designing a tool to send emails from the database. Otherwise I would use chart.js, HTML, Tableau ...

Comment: @HanjunChen - why not send the email with an HTML table embedded in it then? [This might give you some ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44329605/266304).

Comment: @AlexPoole tried HTML, not capable of doing so. It will show the markup in the email.

Comment: @HanjunChen - not if you send it properly, unless it's being read by a plain-text-only mail client; did you set the MIME type? (Again, the answer I linked to handles that for you). If you send it as plain text with space-aligned 'columns' then you're relying on the mail client using a monospaced font. [See this too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51266636/266304).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that should be done as a simple query, not through PL/SQL, but presumably this is an exercise you have been given to specifically do in PL/SQL...

You need to pad the values from the table so they are all the same length. You also don't want the extra space you're currently concatenating really.

Quick example:

```
set serveroutput on

declare
  stringBuilder varchar2(4000);
begin
  stringBuilder := ''; -- default is null anyway
  for i in (select * from produces) loop
    stringBuilder := stringBuilder || rpad(i.name, 10)
      || ' ' || lpad(i.price, 5) || chr(10);
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line(stringBuilder);
end;
/

Apple       $1.3
Orange      $2.6

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

You will need to set the pad values appropriately for your data. And if you add one to either of the padding amounts then you don't need the explicit `' '` to be concatenated into the string.

---

You said in a comment that this is to be sent as part of an email; but even if you include the correct padding to make it look like it's aligned, you're relying on the mail client rendering it in a monospaced font. If the client uses a proportional font then it will look wrong again (as in [this example from Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51266636/266304)). It would be better to send it as an HTML table, with the appropriate MIME type headers on the email. (Or, possibly, as a plain-text attachment - again if you can be sure the recipient will open it in a monospaced-font editor...)