# Send very large HTML message body in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have below piece of code-

```
declare
msg clob;
begin
select email into msg from ANI_CLOB;
Utl_Mail.Send(Sender =>'<abc.def@xyz.com>', Recipients =>abc.def@xyz.com,subject =>'CLOB MESSAGE', MIME_TYPE => 'text/html', Message =>msg);
end;
```

table ANI_CLOB have one column 'EMAIL' with CLOB datatype and only one row where large html email body is stored.

when I run this block I am getting below error -

```
Error report -
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line 5
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints.
```

Can we send CLOB as message body in utl_mail.send.
Also,I want to send this message as mail body only.

Comment: Take this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326026/how-to-export-data-from-log-table-to-email-body-in-oracle/44329605#44329605

Answer (score 0):

No, `UTL_MAIL` does not support `CLOBs`. If you must do this, you will have to use `UTL_SMTP`, handle the different steps of communicating to a mail server yourself, and send the `CLOB` using multiple calls to `utl_smtp.write_data`.