# Chinese language (Other than English) not being sent in email using UTL SMTP in Oracle application

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, smtp

We have a code change to send a email to the user using `UTL_SMTP` in oracle.
We have used HTML to format data in the email.
The email is sent from Oracle Server to Outlook.
Words other than english are being sent incorrectly and those needs to be formatted.

```
SUPPLIER NAME   INVOICE NUMBER  INVOICE DATE    PO NUMBER   CURRENCY    PO AMOUNT   PAID DATE
????????????    1018416-20181106-1  06-NOV-2018 215002655   CNY 208,246.50  06-DEC-2018
????????????????    76782188    14-NOV-2018 215002698   CNY 45,714.29   06-DEC-2018
```

The Chinese words are being shown as Question marks(?????).

Relevant PL/SQL code is this:

```
BEGIN   
            P_Email_ID := cur_r.EMAIL_ID;
            P_REQUISITIONER :=cur_r.REQUISITIONER;
            --recipient:=P_Email_ID;
            fnd_file.put_line(fnd_file.LOG,'TO_Email :'||P_Email_ID);
            fnd_file.put_line(fnd_file.LOG,'Requisitioner :'||P_REQUISITIONER);
            mail_conn := utl_smtp.open_connection(mailhost, 25);
            utl_smtp.helo(mail_conn, mailhost);
            utl_smtp.mail(mail_conn, sender);
            utl_smtp.rcpt(mail_conn, recipient);
            l_message := null;                    
            l_table :=null;

            l_message := l_message||'<html><head>'||crlf||
                         '<style>'||crlf||
                         'thead {color:blue;}'||crlf||
                         'tbody {color:black;}'||crlf||
                         'table, th ,td{border: 1px solid black;}'||crlf||
                         'table {border-collapse: collapse;width: 65%;}'||crlf||
                         'th {height: 25px; text-align: left;}'||crlf||
                         'th, td {padding: 10px;}'||crlf||
                         '</style>'||crlf||
                         '</head>'||crlf||
                         '<body>'||crlf||
                         '<p>Dear ' || P_REQUISITIONER ||'</p>'||crlf||crlf||
                         '<p>Your supplier has been paid.</p>'||crlf||crlf||
                         '<p>This is a notification for information only, do not reply to this email. The supplier will receive a separate remittance advice sent to the email address held in Oracle.</p>'||crlf||crlf||
                         '<p>Payment has been made for the following POs that you raised:</p>'; 

                fnd_file.put_line(fnd_file.log , l_message);

            l_body :=l_body||'<table>'||crlf||
                     '<thead>'||crlf||
                       '<tr>'||crlf||
                          '<th><font size ="2"  face="arial" >SUPPLIER NAME</th>'||crlf||
                          '<th><font size ="2"  face="arial" >INVOICE NUM</th>'||crlf||
                          '<th><font size ="2"  face="arial" >INVOICE DATE</th>'||crlf||
                          '<th><font size ="2"  face="arial" >PO NUMBER</th>'||crlf||
                          '<th><font size ="2"  face="arial" >CURRENCY</th>'||crlf||
                          '<th><font size ="2"  face="arial" >PO AMOUNT</th>'||crlf||
                          '<th><font size ="2"  face="arial" >PAID DATE</th>'||crlf||                                 
                        '</tr>'||crlf||
                        '</thead>'; 

            fnd_file.put_line(fnd_file.LOG,P_Email_ID|| P_OU||L_DATE);  

    FOR cur_req IN SUP_INFO(P_Email_ID,P_OU,L_DATE)
        LOOP
                l_table :=l_table||
                        '<tbody>'||crlf||
                            '<tr>'||crlf||
                                    '<td><font size ="2"  face="arial" >'||cur_req.SUPPLIER_NAME||'</td>'||crlf||
                                    '<td><font size ="2"  face="arial" >'||cur_req.INVOICE_NUM||'</td>'||crlf||
                                    '<td><font size ="2"  face="arial" >'||cur_req.INVOICE_DATE||'</td>'||crlf||
                                    '<td><font size ="2"  face="arial" >'||cur_req.PO_NUMBER||'</td>'||crlf||
                                    '<td><font size ="2"  face="arial" >'||cur_req.INVOICE_CURRENCY||'</td>'||crlf||
                                    '<td><font size ="2"  face="arial" >'||cur_req.PO_AMOUNT||'</td>'||crlf||
                                    '<td><font size ="2"  face="arial" >'||cur_req.PAID_DATE||'</td>'||crlf||                                           
                                '</tr>'||crlf||
                                '</tbody>';

        END LOOP;   
                l_table :=l_table||'</table>'||crlf||
                                '</body></html>';
                fnd_file.put_line(fnd_file.LOG, l_table);               
                  l_message := 'From: <'|| sender ||'>' || crlf ||'Subject: '|| pSubject || crlf ||'To: '||recipient || crlf ||'MIME-Version: 1.0'||crlf||'Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1'||crlf|| '' || crlf || l_message|| crlf || l_body|| crlf || l_table ||crlf;
            utl_smtp.data(mail_conn, l_message || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
            UTL_SMTP.quit(mail_conn);
            fnd_file.put_line(fnd_file.LOG,'Sent mail :');  
            EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
               fnd_file.put_line(fnd_file.LOG,'Email failed'||SQLERRM);
            END;   
END LOOP;
fnd_file.put_line(fnd_file.LOG,'Loop Closed:');
```

Comment: Have a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326026/how-to-export-data-from-log-table-to-email-body-in-oracle/44329605#44329605

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Please check the question i have edited and added the code.

Answer (score 0):

You declare `Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1`. [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) does not support Chinese characters thus they are not displayed.

I would recommend this procedure:

```
PROCEDURE SendMail(
    Subject IN VARCHAR2, 
    Message IN OUT CLOB, 
    ToMail IN VARCHAR2,   
    FromMail IN VARCHAR2, 
    FromName IN VARCHAR2,
    PRIORITY IN INTEGER DEFAULT 3) IS

    PRIORITY_HIGH           CONSTANT INTEGER := 1;
    PRIORITY_NORMAL         CONSTANT INTEGER := 3;
    PRIORITY_LOW            CONSTANT INTEGER := 5;

    MIME_HTML               CONSTANT VARCHAR2(50) := 'text/html;';  
    SMTP_PORT               CONSTANT INTEGER := 25;
    SMTP_SERVER             CONSTANT VARCHAR2(50):= 'mailhost';

    con UTL_SMTP.CONNECTION;
    ret UTL_SMTP.REPLY;
    Charset VARCHAR2(20);

    LobLen INTEGER;
    amount INTEGER := 8000;
    BUFFER VARCHAR2(32000);
    OFFSET INTEGER := 1;

BEGIN

    -- setup mail header
    con := UTL_SMTP.OPEN_CONNECTION(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT);
    ret := UTL_SMTP.HELO(con, SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'DB_DOMAIN'));
    ret := UTL_SMTP.MAIL(con, FromMail);
    ret := UTL_SMTP.RCPT(con, ToMail);
    ret := UTL_SMTP.OPEN_DATA(con);

    IF CONVERT(FromName, 'US7ASCII') = FromName THEN
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, 'From: "'||FromName||'" <'||FromMail||'>'||UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    ELSE
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, 'From: =?UTF-8?B?'|| UTL_ENCODE.TEXT_ENCODE(FromName, 'AL32UTF8', UTL_ENCODE.BASE64) ||'?= <'||FromMail||'>'||UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    END IF; 

    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, 'To: '||ToMail||UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    IF CONVERT(Subject, 'US7ASCII') = Subject THEN
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, 'Subject: '||Subject||UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    ELSE
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, 'Subject: =?UTF-8?B?'|| REPLACE(REPLACE(UTL_ENCODE.TEXT_ENCODE(Subject, 'AL32UTF8', UTL_ENCODE.BASE64), CHR(13), NULL), CHR(10), NULL) ||'?='||UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    END IF;
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, 'Date: '||TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Dy, DD Mon YYYY hh24:mi:ss TZHTZM', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')||UTL_TCP.CRLF);  
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, 'X-Priority: '||PRIORITY||UTL_TCP.CRLF);

    SELECT UTL_I18N.MAP_CHARSET(VALUE)
    INTO Charset
    FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS
    WHERE parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, 'Content-type: '||MIME_HTML||' charset='||Charset || UTL_TCP.CRLF);

    -- Mail Body
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    LobLen := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(Message);
    LOOP
        EXIT WHEN OFFSET > LobLen;
        DBMS_LOB.READ(Message, amount, OFFSET, BUFFER);
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_RAW_DATA(con, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(BUFFER));
        OFFSET := OFFSET + amount;
    END LOOP;   
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, UTL_TCP.CRLF);

    -- finish mail
    ret := UTL_SMTP.CLOSE_DATA(con);
    ret := UTL_SMTP.QUIT(con);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN UTL_SMTP.TRANSIENT_ERROR OR UTL_SMTP.PERMANENT_ERROR THEN
        UTL_SMTP.QUIT(con);
END SendMail;
```