# How to attach an Excel file to an UTL_SMTP package in Oracle for sending an Email

Tags: excel, oracle, smtp

Can Anyone provide the code for Attaching an Excel to an UTL_SMTP mail package in Oracle.

Comment: You asked this last week, right? Did you try the code in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56036932/oracle-sending-email-with-excel-attachment) that I linked?

Comment: You created a Excel, Before sending. i want to attach, which i have already.