# How to send attachments (blob) by email oracle?

Tags: oracle

I need send attachments by email, by plsql procedure i found some code in oracle base website but the attachments not sent ,  how i can send one blob file or multi files in attachment like pdf and word .
     objConnection := UTL_SMTP.open_connection ('mail', 25);

```
UTL_SMTP.helo (objConnection, 'mail');

UTL_SMTP.command (objConnection, 'AUTH LOGIN');

UTL_SMTP.command (objConnection,UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2 (UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode (UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw ('J@GMAIL.COM'))));

UTL_SMTP.mail (objConnection, 'J@GMAIL.COM');

V_TO_EMAIL := 'J@GMAIL.COM';

UTL_SMTP.rcpt (objConnection, 'J@GMAIL.COM');

UTL_SMTP.open_data (objConnection);
UTL_SMTP.write_data (objConnection,'From: ' || 'J@GMAIL.COM' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.write_data (objConnection, 'To: ' || V_TO_EMAIL || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.write_data (objConnection, 'cc: ' || V_TO_EMAIL || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.write_data (objConnection,'Subject: ' || V_TITLE || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.write_data (objConnection,'MIME-Version: ' || '1.0' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.write_data (objConnection, 'Content-Type: ' || 'text/html;'); 
UTL_SMTP.write_data (objConnection,'Content-Transfer-Encoding: ' || '"8Bit"' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.write_data (objConnection, UTL_TCP.CRLF);
UTL_SMTP.write_data (objConnection, UTL_TCP.CRLF || '<HTML>');
UTL_SMTP.write_data (objConnection, UTL_TCP.CRLF || '<BODY>');
UTL_SMTP.write_data (objConnection, UTL_TCP.CRLF || '</BODY>');
UTL_SMTP.write_data (objConnection, UTL_TCP.CRLF || '</HTML>');
UTL_SMTP.close_data (objConnection);
UTL_SMTP.quit (objConnection);
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, code posted on Oracle Base works correctly, so I presume you've done something wrong. What would that be? Who knows ... it is close to impossible to debug code you can't see.

Comment: See this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326026/how-to-export-data-from-log-table-to-email-body-in-oracle/44329605#44329605

Comment: i was added some code in above , how i can edit this code to send attachment files