# Send a XML file encoded UTF-8 via email Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, utf-8

I'm sending XML files via email in Oracle, but at first I had the problem that I needed to apply manually the UTF-8 to open the XML on browsers. So I investigated and before sending the XML, I applied the Oracle CONVERT function:

```
v_xml_factura := CONVERT(v_xml_factura,'AL32UTF8');


XXESC_EMAIL_FILES.Attach_File (v_conn, reg.factura||'.xml', v_xml_factura, 'application/xml' );
```

So with that I can open it on Opera and Chrome browsers, but IE and Firefox I still can't without applying UTF-8 manually.

Can someone give me any hints? Thank you beforehand.

Comment: Can you not just add an `encoding="utf-8"` attribute to the `<?xml>` header element?

Comment: I would be surprised if the XML is not already in UTF-8, so `CONVERT(..., 'AL32UTF8')` seems to be pointless. What is the content of procedure `XXESC_EMAIL_FILES`? Perhaps have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326026/how-to-export-data-from-log-table-to-email-body-in-oracle/44329605#44329605