# Sending large CLOB message using UTL_MAIL.SEND

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle12c

I'm using below code snippet in Oracle 12c procedure.

```
 UTL_MAIL.SEND(SENDER     => 'abc@x.com',
                    RECIPIENTS => 'xyz@x.com',
                    MIME_TYPE => 'text/html',
                    SUBJECT    => SUBJECT,
                    MESSAGE    => EMAIL_STRING);
```

`EMAIL_STRING` is of type `CLOB` It was working fine before. Now the email string **length** has been increased (became **62598** which is dynamic) and started giving below error.

```
Error report -
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "PROCEDURE_NAME", line 67
ORA-06512: at line 1
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints.
```

How to send large CLOB as message body using `UTL_MAIL.SEND` ?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326026/how-to-export-data-from-log-table-to-email-body-in-oracle/44329605#44329605

Comment: Thanks @Wernfried Domscheit. This is using UTL_SMTP . Is it possible to do it using UTL_MAIL ?

Comment: I never used ` UTL_MAIL`, which seems to be much simpler (and thus also provide much less functions) than  UTL_SMTP

Comment: Looks like it is not possible: [message     IN    **VARCHAR2** CHARACTER SET ANY_CS,](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/UTL_MAIL.html#GUID-E8410400-A1B5-4DEC-88BF-3851C7C16AF6)

Comment: If APEX_MAIL is available to you, that package makes it very easy to send emails: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aeapi/SEND-Function-Signature-1.html#GUID-760A11B9-3CB9-435C-9289-C2F2791BB80C

Comment: Sure @EJ Egyed. Will check that too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As @Wernfried Domscheit commented, I followed [how to export data from log table to email body in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326026/how-to-export-data-from-log-table-to-email-body-in-oracle/44329605#44329605) and used below snippet in my procedure to call the newly created package.

```
MAILING.SendMail(
        Subject => SUBJECT, 
        Message => EMAIL_STRING, 
        ToMail => VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE('toEmailid1','toEmailid2'),   
        FromMail => 'fromEmailId', 
        FromName => 'fromName');
```