# Oracle UTL_SMTP closing connection

Tags: oracle, plsql, connection

This is example of procedure that I'm using to send mail

```
BEGIN
    l_mail_conn := UTL_SMTP.OPEN_CONNECTION(c_mailhost, c_port);
    UTL_SMTP.HELO(l_mail_conn, c_mailhost);
    UTL_SMTP.MAIL(l_mail_conn, p_sender);
    UTL_SMTP.RCPT(l_mail_conn, p_recipient);
    --Create HEADER
    l_head := 'MIME-Version: 1.0' || UTL_TCP.crlf
        || 'To: ' || p_recipient || UTL_TCP.crlf
        || 'From: ' || p_sender || UTL_TCP.crlf
        || 'Subject: ' || p_subject || UTL_TCP.crlf
        || 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="' || g_mime_bound || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf
        --|| UTL_TCP.crlf
        || 'This is a multi-part message in MIME format.' || UTL_TCP.crlf
        || '--' || g_mime_bound || UTL_TCP.crlf
        || 'Content-Type: ' || p_type || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf
        --|| 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable ' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf
    ;
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_head);
    --Write HEADER
    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(l_body, false, 10);
    DBMS_LOB.WRITE(l_body, LENGTH(l_head), 1, l_head);
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_body);
    --Write BODY
    l_offset := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(l_body) + 1;
    DBMS_LOB.WRITE(l_body, LENGTH(p_data), l_offset, p_data);
    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_body);
    l_offset := 1;
    UTL_SMTP.OPEN_DATA(l_mail_conn);
    WHILE l_offset < DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(l_body) 
    LOOP
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_RAW_DATA(l_mail_conn, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(l_body, l_ammount, l_offset)));
        l_offset := l_offset + l_ammount;
        l_ammount := LEAST(1900, DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(l_body) - l_ammount);
    END LOOP;
    --Clear DATA
    UTL_SMTP.CLOSE_DATA(l_mail_conn);
    UTL_SMTP.QUIT(l_mail_conn);
    DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(l_body);
END;
```

And it works as intended, problem is with closing connections. My best guess is that if procedure breaks somewhere between opening connection and closing it, connection stays open. When that happens enough times, I get

```
ERROR: ORA-30678: too many open connections
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_TCP", line 17
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_TCP", line 267
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 161
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 197
```

So I've decided to add closing connection to my EXCEPTION block. But while I was testing, I realized that I can't run UTL_SMTP.QUIT(l_mail_conn) if connection is not open, if I try it I get

```
ORA-29278: SMTP transient error: 421 Service not available
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 54
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 138
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 699
```

So then I found out there is function called NOOP I can use to determine if connection is open or not, so I tried that one, and it works some times, if I call it before connection is open, I get

```
421
Service not available
```

And if I call it after connection is open, I get

```
250
Ok
```

But if I try to call it after while loop or inside it (before data is closed), procedure breaks again with following error

```
ORA-29277: invalid SMTP operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 80
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 210
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 677
```

As a temporary fix, I simply added utl_tcp.close_all_connections; in my exception block, but it's not something I would like to do (cause it could potentially break other procedured using UTL_SMTP at the same time)

So I just need a way to make sure connection is closed no matter what happens. Does anyone knows how it should be done?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326026/how-to-export-data-from-log-table-to-email-body-in-oracle/44329605#44329605

Comment: an exception handler would take care of it, but the easier way is just to install APEX (even if you NEVER use APEX). You get all sorts of useful utilities and one of those is APEX_MAIL which takes away all of the complexity