# How do we configure email alerts when a tablespace is full in oracle database in windows os

Tags: windows, oracle, oracle12c

any script where i can create a batch job to run via windows task scheduler

i am able to get a script when the tablespace is full but wanted  that output to trigger an email to a specific address any suggestions please

**below is the script which i have mentioned above**
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

```
SET ECHO OFF; SET TERM OFF; 
SET TIMING OFF; 
SET HEAD OFF; 
SET FEED OFF; 
CREATE TABLE temp_ts(tablespace_name,total_bytes,free_bytes,max_chunk)   AS   SELECT
   tablespace_name, NVL(SUM(bytes), 1), 1, 1   FROM dba_data_files  
   GROUP BY tablespace_name;   UPDATE temp_ts a   SET a.free_bytes =
   (SELECT NVL(SUM(b.bytes), 1)
                         FROM dba_free_space b
                         WHERE b.tablespace_name = a.tablespace_name);   COMMIT;
       UPDATE temp_ts a   SET a.max_chunk = (SELECT NVL(MAX(b.bytes), 1)
                        FROM dba_free_space b
                        WHERE b.tablespace_name = a.tablespace_name);   COMMIT;   REM ************************   REM Display tablespaces
   more than 95% full.   SELECT tablespace_name                        
   ||
            ' is '                                              ||
            TO_CHAR(ROUND(100-(free_bytes*100/total_bytes), 2)) ||
            '% full.' Tablename   FROM temp_ts   WHERE 95 < 100-(free_bytes*100/total_bytes)   ORDER BY tablespace_name;
```

the output will be the tablespacename along with the percentage
now i want that output to trigger an email if it is crossing the more than 95%

any suggestions ??

Comment: Typically this would be handled by 3rd-party monitoring software, such as Oracle Enterprise Manager, SolarWinds, Quest Foglight, etc. Scripting this on Linux would be relatively simple, as there is an e-mail client built in to the OS and you would only need to point it to a mail relay. To run a script on Windows you would need to find a command-line e-mail client (good luck) or perhaps use the Linux subsystem for Windows. Alternatively you could configure the database to use your SQL and send e-mail directly from a stored procedure, but would need to setup DB ACLs and the target mail-relay.

Comment: Maybe like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326026/how-to-export-data-from-log-table-to-email-body-in-oracle/44329605#44329605