# UTL_SMTP trying to attach multiptle files greater than size 32k

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, smtp, email-attachments

I have a stored PL/SQL procedure that reads data from table and mails them as attachments. The data are stored in l_clob2 and l_clob and here I am trying to attach these two as two sperate email attachments in a single mail. I am able to properly  send a single attachment  but I'm unable to send two at a time . When I tried to send two only the first attachment went with the mail . I dont know where I made a mistake . Can anyone help me ?

Here is my code

```
l_clob2 clob; // contains data for attachment 1

l_clob  clob; // contains data  for attachment 2

c_mime_boundary clob := '-----AABCDEFBBCCC0123456789DE';
v_index integer;
v_len integer;
v_index1 integer;
v_len1 integer;

v_Mail_Conn := utl_smtp.Open_Connection(v_Mail_Host, 25);

utl_smtp.Helo(v_Mail_Conn, v_Mail_Host);

utl_smtp.Mail(v_Mail_Conn, v_From);

utl_smtp.Rcpt(v_Mail_Conn, v_Recipient);

utl_smtp.OPEN_DATA(v_Mail_Conn);

  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, 'From: ' || v_From || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, 'To: ' || v_Recipient || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, 'Subject: ' || REPLACE(v_Subject, '[DATE]',TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD.MM.YYYY')) || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, 'MIME-Version: 1.0' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn,  'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="' || c_mime_boundary || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  
-- mail body
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, '--' || c_mime_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, V_mail_message );
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  
  -- Set up attachment header
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, '--' || c_mime_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' || 'file1.csv' || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, UTL_TCP.crlf);

  -- Write attachment contents
  v_len := DBMS_LOB.getlength(l_clob2);
  v_index := 1;

  WHILE v_index <= v_len
  LOOP
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(l_clob2, 32000, v_index));
    v_index := v_index + 32000;
  END LOOP;
  
  -- End attachment
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, '--' || c_mime_boundary || '--' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  
   -- Set up attachment header 2
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, '--' || c_mime_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' || 'file2.csv' || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, UTL_TCP.crlf);
  
  v_len1 := DBMS_LOB.getlength(l_clob);
  v_index1 := 1;

  WHILE v_index1 <= v_len1
  LOOP
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(l_clob, 32000, v_index1));
    v_index1 := v_index1 + 32000;
  END LOOP;

  -- End attachment2
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, '--' || c_mime_boundary || '--' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  
utl_smtp.CLOSE_DATA(v_mail_conn);
utl_smtp.Quit(v_mail_conn);
```

Comment: are you using `utl_smtp` for any reason in particular ? I had the same requirement and I went for `apex_mail` which is much easier to handle. There are a couple of nice articles in google on how to add multiple attachments to `utl_smtp`.

Comment: I guess it is some low-level stuff. Perhaps open an existing mail with multiple attachments and have a careful look the raw mail data. Maybe you have to use two different `c_mime_boundary`. Perhaps compare with my one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326026/how-to-export-data-from-log-table-to-email-body-in-oracle/44329605#44329605