# sending a mail when exception occurs in oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, email, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a oracle stored procedure that reads some value from a table. I want the procedure to mail the user if some exception or error occurs in the procedure and the procedure fails. I have written the code and I have created an error on purpose to test if a mail is send to user or not. But some how  my procedure doesn't send a mail if an error occurs. Can someone tell me where I made the mistake ?

The exception I raise to try to trigger the sending of an email:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at "UPDATER.UNLOCK_AND_EMAIL_DUMP", line 19
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

code :

```
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  v_mail_conn2 := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(v_Mail_Host, 25);
  
  UTL_SMTP.helo(v_mail_conn2, v_Mail_Host);
  
  UTL_SMTP.mail(v_mail_conn2, v_From);
  
  UTL_SMTP.rcpt(v_mail_conn2, v_Recipient);
  
  UTL_SMTP.open_data(v_mail_conn2);
  
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_mail_conn2, 'Date: ' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_mail_conn2, 'To: ' || v_Recipient || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_mail_conn2, 'From: ' || v_From || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_mail_conn2, 'Subject: ' || v_Subject || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_mail_conn2, err_message || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  
  UTL_SMTP.close_data(v_mail_conn2);
  
  UTL_SMTP.quit(v_mail_conn2);
  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ( 'Error raised: '|| DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE || ' - '||sqlerrm);

END UNLOCK_AND_EMAIL_DUMP;
```

Comment: Which is line 19? I assume this procedure runs by a job (otherwise an email notification would be pointless), in this case `DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line` does not make any sense. Better put the `ERROR_BACKTRACE` and `SQLERRM` in the mail. Maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326026/how-to-export-data-from-log-table-to-email-body-in-oracle/44329605#44329605

Comment: Schema `SYSTEM` is not the place where you should put any custom packages - `system.intranet_utils`. Create an application user and put your packages there.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit  yes this runs by a job and line 19 is where the error hits ... i have given wrong datatype over there on purpose to create an error so that I can test the mail part . I just want the user to get a mail saying the prcedure has failed without any details

Comment: Your code does not show any line numbers. Again, please highlight line 19.

Comment: Why are you handcrafting this low-level routine? Oracle has provided a built-in library [`utl_mail`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/UTL_MAIL.html#GUID-47AE34E9-3123-4115-AC86-4FF538DBFBBB) for over a decade. It needs DBA assistance to install, but that's because sending email from the database has security and system configuration issues.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - that error is a McGuffin in the code, which is supposed to trigger the sending of an email. The Seeker isn't trying to fix that error, rather they want to know why that exception didn't result in an email being sent.

Comment: Maybe put another exception handler inside your exception handler which shows the error message related to `UTL_SMTP`.