# Unable to send mail with an attachment through Oracle using UTL_SMTP

Tags: oracle, email, smtp

I am trying to send a **mail with an attachment**  through oracle. But I am getting
**Oracle error - ORA-29279: SMTP permanent error: 554 Transaction failed: Expected ';', got "/"message**

in my code at below mentioned step.

L_STEP := 32;
UTL_SMTP.CLOSE_DATA(L_CONNECTION);

I am not able to understand where I am making a mistake.

Calling procedure like -

```
USP_SEND_MAIL(P_TO        => 'rahul.more@XYZ.com',
              P_CC        => 'vishal.patil@XYZ.com',
              P_BCC       => NULL,
              P_FROM      =>'abc@xyz.com',
              P_SUBJECT   => 'Test mail',
              P_FILENAME1 => 'Test_File-27 APR 2022 - 12 PM.xls',
              P_HTML      => '<BR> Dear Sir/Madam <BR>
                                             <BR> Please find attached file.<BR>
                                             <BR> Total count-66<BR>
                                             <BR>Regards <BR> System generated Mailer',
              P_ERR_FLAG  => L_ERR_FLAG);
```

Below is my code

```
PROCEDURE USP_SEND_MAIL     (P_TO        IN VARCHAR2,
                             P_CC        IN VARCHAR2,
                             P_BCC       IN VARCHAR2,
                             P_FROM      IN VARCHAR2,
                             P_SUBJECT   IN VARCHAR2,
                             P_FILENAME1 VARCHAR2,
                             P_HTML      LONG,
                             P_ERR_FLAG  OUT NUMBER) IS
    L_CONNECTION    UTL_SMTP.CONNECTION;
    P_SMTP_HOSTNAME VARCHAR2(100);
    P_SMTP_PORTNUM  VARCHAR2(100);
    L_STEP          INTEGER := 0;
    L_TO            VARCHAR2(4000);
    L_CC            VARCHAR2(4000);
    L_BCC           VARCHAR2(4000);

    CURSOR C1 IS
     SELECT 0, 
       'CERTIFICATE' EBIZ_DATA
      FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT *
      FROM (SELECT 1, t.CERT_NO
            FROM CERTIFICATE t
            ORDER BY 1)
      ORDER BY 1;

  BEGIN
    L_STEP := 1;
    -----***** STAGING MAILER CONFIG ****--------
    P_SMTP_HOSTNAME := 'email-*********.amazonaws.com';
    P_SMTP_PORTNUM := '000';
    L_CONNECTION := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(P_SMTP_HOSTNAME,
                                           P_SMTP_PORTNUM,
                                           wallet_path  => '*****/oracle19c/owm/wallets',
                                           wallet_password => '********',
                                           secure_connection_before_smtp => FALSE);
    L_STEP := 2;
    -----***** STAGING MAILER CONFIG ****--------
    utl_smtp.helo(L_CONNECTION, P_SMTP_HOSTNAME);
    
    --utl_smtp.command(L_CONNECTION, 'STARTTLS');
    utl_smtp.starttls(L_CONNECTION);
  
    utl_smtp.command(L_CONNECTION, 'AUTH LOGIN');
    utl_smtp.command(L_CONNECTION,
                     utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw('********'))));
    utl_smtp.command(L_CONNECTION,
                     utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw('********'))));
    

    L_STEP := 3;
    UTL_SMTP.HELO(L_CONNECTION, P_SMTP_HOSTNAME);
    UTL_SMTP.MAIL(L_CONNECTION, P_FROM);
    
    FOR x IN (SELECT LEVEL AS id,
                   REGEXP_SUBSTR(P_TO, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) AS TO_EMAIL_NAME
              FROM DUAL
            CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(P_TO, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL) LOOP
      utl_smtp.Rcpt(L_CONNECTION, x.TO_EMAIL_NAME);
  END LOOP;

  IF P_CC IS NOT NULL THEN
    FOR x IN (SELECT LEVEL AS id,
                     REGEXP_SUBSTR(P_CC, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) AS CC_EMAIL_NAME
                FROM DUAL
              CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(P_CC, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL) LOOP
      utl_smtp.Rcpt(L_CONNECTION, x.CC_EMAIL_NAME);
      L_CC := L_CC || 'CC: ' || x.CC_EMAIL_NAME || CRLF;
    END LOOP;
  ELSE
    L_CC := '';
  END IF;

  IF P_BCC IS NOT NULL THEN
    FOR x IN (SELECT LEVEL AS id,
                     REGEXP_SUBSTR(P_BCC, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) AS BCC_EMAIL_NAME
                FROM DUAL
              CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(P_BCC, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL) LOOP
      utl_smtp.Rcpt(L_CONNECTION, x.BCC_EMAIL_NAME);
      L_BCC := L_BCC || 'BCC: ' || x.BCC_EMAIL_NAME || CRLF;
    END LOOP;
  ELSE
    L_BCC := '';
  END IF;
    
    L_STEP := 8;
    UTL_SMTP.OPEN_DATA(L_CONNECTION);
    L_STEP := 9;
    -- Use MIME mail header
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_CONNECTION, 'MIME-Version: 1.0' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    L_STEP := 10;
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_CONNECTION,
                        'Date: ' ||
                        TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'Dy, DD Mon YYYY hh24:mi:ss') || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    L_STEP := 11;
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_CONNECTION, 'TO: ' || P_TO || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    
    IF L_CC IS NOT NULL THEN
       L_STEP := 12;
      --UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_CONNECTION, 'Cc: ' || P_CC || UTL_TCP.crlf);
      UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_CONNECTION, L_CC);
    END IF;
    
    IF L_BCC IS NOT NULL THEN
       L_STEP := 13;
      --UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_CONNECTION, 'Bcc: ' || P_BCC || UTL_TCP.crlf);
      UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_CONNECTION, L_BCC);
    END IF;
    
    L_STEP := 14;
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_CONNECTION, 'From: ' || P_FROM || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    L_STEP := 15;
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_CONNECTION, 'Subject: ' || P_SUBJECT || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    L_STEP := 16;
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_CONNECTION, 'Reply-To: ' || P_FROM || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    L_STEP := 17;
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_CONNECTION,
                        'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="EBIZ_BOUNDARY"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    L_STEP := 18;
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_CONNECTION, 'This is multipart message' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    L_STEP := 19;
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_CONNECTION, '--EBIZ_BOUNDARY' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    L_STEP := 20;
    -- Message body
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_CONNECTION, 'Content-Type: text/html;' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    L_STEP := 21;
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_CONNECTION, 'Content-Transfer_Encoding: 7bit' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    L_STEP := 22;
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_CONNECTION, P_HTML || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    L_STEP := 23;
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_CONNECTION, ' ' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    L_STEP := 24;
    -- Attachment section 1
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_CONNECTION, '--EBIZ_BOUNDARY' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    L_STEP := 25;
    --UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_CONNECTION, 'CONTENT-TYPE: TEXT/PLAIN;' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_CONNECTION,
                        'CONTENT-TYPE: APPLICATION/APPLICATION/VND.OPENXMLFORMATS-OFFICEDOCUMENT.SPREADSHEETML.SHEET;' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    L_STEP := 26;
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_CONNECTION,
                        ' NAME="' || P_FILENAME1 || '"' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    L_STEP := 27;
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_CONNECTION,
                        'CONTENT-TRANSFER_ENCODING: 8BIT' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    L_STEP := 28;
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_CONNECTION,
                        'CONTENT-DISPOSITION: ATTACHMENT;' || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    L_STEP := 29;
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_CONNECTION,
                        ' FILENAME="' || P_FILENAME1 || '"' || UTL_TCP.CRLF || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    L_STEP := 30;
    FOR X IN C1 LOOP
      UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_CONNECTION, X.EBIZ_DATA || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    END LOOP;
    -- End MIME mail

    L_STEP := 31;
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_CONNECTION, UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf || '--EBIZ_BOUNDARY--');

    L_STEP := 32;  **GETTING AN ERROR HERE**
    UTL_SMTP.CLOSE_DATA(L_CONNECTION);

    L_STEP := 33;
    UTL_SMTP.QUIT(L_CONNECTION);

    P_ERR_FLAG := 0;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN UTL_SMTP.INVALID_OPERATION THEN
      P_ERR_FLAG := 1;
      IL_ERROR_LOGGING.ERROR(MESSAGE     => SQLERRM || 'message',
                             MODULE      => 'RETAIL UNSYNC POLICY MAILER',
                             V_PARAMATER => (PARAMS(' L_STEP =>' || L_STEP)));                     
      UTL_SMTP.QUIT(L_CONNECTION);
                                
    WHEN UTL_SMTP.TRANSIENT_ERROR THEN
      P_ERR_FLAG := 1;
      IL_ERROR_LOGGING.ERROR(MESSAGE     => SQLERRM || 'message',
                           MODULE      => 'RETAIL UNSYNC POLICY MAILER',
                           V_PARAMATER => (PARAMS(' L_STEP =>' || L_STEP)));                     
      UTL_SMTP.QUIT(L_CONNECTION);
      
    WHEN UTL_SMTP.PERMANENT_ERROR THEN
      P_ERR_FLAG := 1;
      IL_ERROR_LOGGING.ERROR(MESSAGE     => SQLERRM || 'message',
                           MODULE      => 'RETAIL UNSYNC POLICY MAILER',
                           V_PARAMATER => (PARAMS(' L_STEP =>' || L_STEP)));
      UTL_SMTP.QUIT(L_CONNECTION);
      
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
       P_ERR_FLAG := 99;
       IL_ERROR_LOGGING.ERROR(MESSAGE     => SQLERRM || 'message',
                           MODULE      => 'RETAIL UNSYNC POLICY MAILER',
                           V_PARAMATER => (PARAMS(' L_STEP =>' || L_STEP)));
      UTL_SMTP.QUIT(L_CONNECTION);
      
  END;
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326026/how-to-export-data-from-log-table-to-email-body-in-oracle/44329605#44329605

Comment: Data type `LONG` is deprecated for ages, you should not use it. Try `CLOB` instead.