# How to re-design code with UTL_SMTP - Oracle Apex send mail

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

It's been a hard time not able to make my code to work with `UTL_SMTP` package.

Can some one guide me to change below code and make it work with `UTL_SMTP` method

I created a mailing application which sends mail to all user on their email id's with an attachment.

**Took reference and I built it same exactly like this**

https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/post/creating-email-campaign-app-with-oracle-apex

**My Code :**

```
    declare 
        l_context apex_exec.t_context;    
        l_emailsidx  pls_integer;
        l_namesids    pls_integer;
        l_region_id number;
    begin
        -- Get the region id for the CUSTOMERS IR region
        select region_id
          into l_region_id
          from apex_application_page_regions
         where application_id = :APP_ID
           and page_id        = 1
           and static_id      = 'CUSTOMERS';
     
        l_context := apex_region.open_query_context (
                            p_page_id => 1,
                            p_region_id => l_region_id );
        -- Get the column positions for EMAIL and NAME columns
        l_emailsidx := apex_exec.get_column_position( l_context, 'EMAIL' );
        l_namesids := apex_exec.get_column_position( l_context, 'NAME' );
        
        -- Loop throught the query of the context
        while apex_exec.next_row( l_context ) loop        
            l_id : = apex_mail.send (
            p_to                 => apex_exec.get_varchar2( l_context, l_emailsidx ),
            p_template_static_id => 'NEW_YEAR_2020_PROMOTION_DUBAI_BRANCH',
            p_placeholders       => '{' ||
            '    "CUSTOMER":'            || apex_json.stringify( apex_exec.get_varchar2( l_context, l_namesids )) ||
            '   ,"START_DATE":'          || apex_json.stringify( :P2_START_DATE ) ||
            '   ,"END_DATE":'            || apex_json.stringify( :P2_END_DATE ) ||        
            '   ,"LOCATION":'            || apex_json.stringify( :P2_LOCATION ) ||        
            '   ,"NOTES":'               || apex_json.stringify( :P2_NOTES ) ||
            '   ,"ITEMS":'               || apex_json.stringify( :P2_ITEMS ) ||
            '   ,"MY_APPLICATION_LINK":' || apex_json.stringify( apex_mail.get_instance_url || apex_page.get_url( 1 )) ||        
            '}' );
         end loop;
         

for rec in (
        select filename, blob_content, mime_type 
          from apex_application_files
         where flow_id = :APP_ID
           and filename = 'apex_logo.png'
    ) 
    loop

        apex_mail.add_attachment(
            p_mail_id    => l_id,
            p_attachment => rec.blob_content,
            p_filename   => rec.filename,
            p_mime_type  => rec.mime_type);
    end loop;

         apex_mail_queue(
             p_smtp_hostname => 'xyz.xmp.it',
             p_smtp_portno   => 45
         )

         apex_exec.close( l_context );
    exception
         when others then
             apex_exec.close( l_context );
         raise; 
    end;
```

**Need to convert my above code below like this**

```
UTL_MAIL.send (
 sender => 'example@ac.cc',
 recipents => 'abcexample@ac.cc',
 cc => 'xyzexample@ac.cc',
 subject => 'Testing',
 mime_type => 'text/html',
 message => 'ABC TESTING' 
);
```

**My below code does not support at my end. It throws network access denied as (ACL). Only UTL_SMTP is supported and mail is sent. But below code need to transform as above** `UTL_SMTP.send` **method**

```
  l_id : = apex_mail.send (
            p_to                 => apex_exec.get_varchar2( l_context, l_emailsidx ),
            p_template_static_id => 'NEW_YEAR_2020_PROMOTION_DUBAI_BRANCH',
            p_placeholders       => '{' ||
            '    "CUSTOMER":'            || apex_json.stringify( apex_exec.get_varchar2( l_context, l_namesids )) ||
            '   ,"START_DATE":'          || apex_json.stringify( :P2_START_DATE ) ||
            '   ,"END_DATE":'            || apex_json.stringify( :P2_END_DATE ) ||        
            '   ,"LOCATION":'            || apex_json.stringify( :P2_LOCATION ) ||        
            '   ,"NOTES":'               || apex_json.stringify( :P2_NOTES ) ||
            '   ,"ITEMS":'               || apex_json.stringify( :P2_ITEMS ) ||
            '   ,"MY_APPLICATION_LINK":' || apex_json.stringify( apex_mail.get_instance_url || apex_page.get_url( 1 )) ||        
            '}' );
         end loop;
         

for rec in (
        select filename, blob_content, mime_type 
          from apex_application_files
         where flow_id = :APP_ID
           and filename = 'apex_logo.png'
    ) 
    loop

        apex_mail.add_attachment(
            p_mail_id    => l_id,
            p_attachment => rec.blob_content,
            p_filename   => rec.filename,
            p_mime_type  => rec.mime_type);
    end loop;

         apex_mail_queue(
             p_smtp_hostname => 'xyz.xmp.it',
             p_smtp_portno   => 45
         )
```

**Following is the YouTube followed to create the application**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZQ04yjS7rQ

Comment: To me this is a wrong approach. Rather than rewriting your code to a much more complex pattern, because apex_mail throws an ACL error... why don't you just fix the ACL error ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie : Lots of restriction not able to do so. That's a reason i want to make it compatible to UTL_SMTP.

Comment: Ok. This will be a big task that probably no one has ever done.

Comment: @KoenLostrie  : Ya its a big task but no where their any videos for this. Someone should take the initiative to come up with the solution. Stackoverflow is meant for that only.

Comment: @KoenLostrie : Need help for this

Comment: See this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326026/how-to-export-data-from-log-table-to-email-body-in-oracle/44329605#44329605