# How to implement email with attachment | UTL_SMTP | PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am not getting how to implement it.

**Requirement :**

Need to add attachment option to my code [ `The attachment might be pdf, doc, txt` ].

And it should be optional. If I attach then send mail with attachment or else simple send the Html message which is written.

**My procedure**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE send_mail (p_to        IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_from      IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_subject   IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_html_msg  IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                       p_attach_name IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                       p_attach_mime IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                       p_attach_blob IN BLOB DEFAULT NULL,
                                       p_smtp_host IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_smtp_port IN NUMBER DEFAULT 25)
AS
  l_mail_conn   UTL_SMTP.connection;
  l_boundary    VARCHAR2(50) := '----=*#abc1234321cba#*=';
BEGIN
  l_mail_conn := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(p_smtp_host, p_smtp_port);
  UTL_SMTP.helo(l_mail_conn, p_smtp_host);
  UTL_SMTP.mail(l_mail_conn, p_from);
  UTL_SMTP.rcpt(l_mail_conn, p_to);

  UTL_SMTP.open_data(l_mail_conn);
  
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Date: ' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'To: ' || p_to || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'From: ' || p_from || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Subject: ' || p_subject || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Reply-To: ' || p_from || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'MIME-Version: 1.0' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="' || l_boundary || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    
  IF p_html_msg IS NOT NULL THEN
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);

    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, p_html_msg);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  END IF;


  IF p_attach_name IS NOT NULL THEN
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: ' || p_attach_mime || '; name="' || p_attach_name || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' || p_attach_name || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);

    FOR i IN 0 .. TRUNC((DBMS_LOB.getlength(p_attach_blob) - 1 )/l_step) LOOP
      UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(DBMS_LOB.substr(p_attach_blob, l_step, i * l_step + 1))) || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    END LOOP;

    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.crlf);
  END IF;


  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || '--' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.close_data(l_mail_conn);

  UTL_SMTP.quit(l_mail_conn);
END;
/
```

**Calling**

```
DECLARE

  l_name attachment_details.filename %TYPE;
  l_blob attachment_details.fblob%TYPE;
  l_mime attachment_details.mimetype%TYPE;

BEGIN
  SELECT fblob 
  INTO   l_blob
  FROM   attachment_details
  WHERE  filename = 'ABC.txt';

  SELECT MIMETYPE
  INTO   l_mime 
  FROM   attachment_details
  WHERE  filename = 'ABC.txt';

  SELECT filename 
  INTO   l_name 
  FROM   attachment_details
  WHERE  filename = 'ABC.txt';

  
  send_mail(p_to          => 'me@mycompany.com',
            p_from        => 'admin@mycompany.com',
            p_subject     => 'Test Message',
            p_html_msg    => '<html> <body> <h1> Hi friends !!! </h1> </body> </html>',
            p_attach_name => l_name ,
            p_attach_mime => l_mime ,
            p_attach_blob => l_blob,
            p_smtp_host   => 'smtp.mycompany.com');
END;
/
```

**My blob table which as pdf , doc , txt file**

```
create table attachment_details 
(
fblob blob,
filename varchar2(4000 char),
mimetype varchar2(4000 char),
createddate varchar2(4000 char)
);
```

**Data in table :** `attachment_details`

```
fblob , filename  , mimetype , createddate 
(BLOB), ABC.txt   , application/open.... , 10-JAN-22
(BLOB), XYZ.pdf   , application/open.... , 10-JAN-22
```

It throws me error at line : `send_mail(p_to          => 'me@mycompany.com',`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326026/how-to-export-data-from-log-table-to-email-body-in-oracle/44329605#44329605

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit : Not getting how to do ? any working code will be good

Comment: The linked answer provides a ready-to-use code.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit : I want to attach my file which is their in my table not log file

Comment: Simply attach the BLOB you select. It's one of the input parameters.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit : Can you show with an example with my own code added to question

Comment: Seriously? Call it in the same way as your procedure `send_mail` in the question. Just the procedure name and the parameter names are slightly different.

Comment: You say "It throws me error at ...". It would be very helpful if you could tell us the actual error!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to export data from log table to email body in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326026/how-to-export-data-from-log-table-to-email-body-in-oracle)