# Auto Email notification when a field is modified

Tags: sql

Is there a way to track or alert if the 'Tax Exempt status' is modified in a table(and by which user)?

this is the select statement I came up with to see the data

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       JOB_job_id,
       job_taxable_indicator,
       act_CREATION_DATE,
       SEC_USER_ID,
       SEC_USER_NAME
FROM BI50_JOB_COST_V1
WHERE JOB_JOB_ID = 220001
ORDER BY ACT_CREATION_DATE
```

Comment: Oracle <> SQL Server. Also, *please* get into the habit of formatting when writing; single single of code are notoriously difficult to read and debug.

Comment: Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326026/how-to-export-data-from-log-table-to-email-body-in-oracle/44329605#44329605