# Unable to send attachment through PL/SQL for multiple lines inside attachment using UTL_SMTP

Tags: oracle, plsql

Can someone help me with UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA for sending email with attachment.  I am not able to send attachment with multiple lines inside code.

When I write UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA to write data inside attachment it doesn't work.

Below is the attached code which sends attachment for only 1 row from second cursor when i=1.

Someone please help.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY xx_common_alerts_pkg AS

    gv_process_name   CONSTANT VARCHAR2(100) := 'Common Alert Functionality';


    PROCEDURE main (
        po_errbuf      OUT            VARCHAR2,
        po_retcode     OUT            NUMBER,
            --   p_debug    IN  NUMBER,
        p_alert_name   IN             VARCHAR2
    ) IS

        lv_procedure             CONSTANT VARCHAR2(200) := 'XX_COMMON_ALERTS_PKG.main';
        lv_to_recipients         alr_actions.to_recipients%TYPE;
        lv_cc_recipients         alr_actions.cc_recipients%TYPE;
        lv_bcc_recipients        alr_actions.bcc_recipients%TYPE;
        lv_subject               alr_actions.subject%TYPE;
        lv_alert_id              alr_alerts.alert_id%TYPE;
        lv_row_count             alr_action_set_checks.row_count%TYPE;
        lv_check_id              alr_action_set_checks.alert_check_id%TYPE;
        v_clob                   CLOB := empty_clob();
        v_clob_lines             CLOB := empty_clob();
        lv_mail_body_lines       VARCHAR2(30000);
        lv_ctxh                  dbms_xmlgen.ctxhandle;
        lv_queryresult           XMLTYPE;
        lv_xslt_transform        XMLTYPE;
        lv_message               VARCHAR2(30000);
        lv_error_msg             VARCHAR2(3000);
        lv_inst_name             VARCHAR2(50);
        lv_from_email            VARCHAR2(100);
        lv_to_email              VARCHAR2(100);
        lv_recipients_mail       VARCHAR2(100);
        lv_status                VARCHAR2(30000);
        lv_alert_check_id        VARCHAR2(2000);
        lv_list_id               alr_actions.list_id%TYPE;
        lv_list_application_id   alr_actions.list_application_id%TYPE;
        lv_body                  alr_actions.body%TYPE;
        lv_ret_message           VARCHAR2(2000);
        lv_ret_status            VARCHAR2(2000);
        lv_attach_tab            t_attach_tab := t_attach_tab();
        v_from                   VARCHAR2(80) := 'abc@gmail.com';
        v_recipient              VARCHAR2(80) := 'def@gmail.com';
        v_subject                VARCHAR2(80) := 'test';
        v_mail_host              VARCHAR2(80) := 'mlocalhost'; --localhost';
        v_smtp_port              NUMBER := 25;
        v_mail_conn              utl_smtp.connection;
        l_step                   PLS_INTEGER := 12000;
        crlf                     VARCHAR2(2) := chr(13)
                            || chr(10);
        v_len                    INTEGER;
        v_index                  INTEGER := 1;
        le_mail_excp EXCEPTION;
        CURSOR c_get_alert_outputs (
            pi_alert_id VARCHAR2
        ) IS
        SELECT
            name,
            title
        FROM
            alr_alert_outputs
        WHERE
            alert_id = pi_alert_id
            AND end_date_active IS NULL
        ORDER BY
            name DESC;

        CURSOR c_output_lines (
            pi_check_id NUMBER,
            pi_row_number NUMBER
        ) IS
        SELECT DISTINCT
            value,
            name
        FROM
            alr_output_history
        WHERE
            check_id = pi_check_id
            AND row_number = pi_row_number
        ORDER BY
            name DESC;

    BEGIN   

        SELECT
            actions.to_recipients,
            actions.cc_recipients,
            actions.bcc_recipients,
            actions.subject,
            alr.alert_id,
            actions.list_id,
            actions.list_application_id,
            actions.body
        INTO
            lv_to_recipients,
            lv_cc_recipients,
            lv_bcc_recipients,
            lv_subject,
            lv_alert_id,
            lv_list_id,
            lv_list_application_id,
            lv_body
        FROM
            alr_alerts alr,
            alr_actions actions
        WHERE
            alr.alert_name = p_alert_name
            AND alr.alert_id = actions.alert_id
            AND actions.name = 'Send Email'
            AND actions.enabled_flag = 'Y'
            AND actions.end_date_active IS NULL;

        IF lv_list_id IS NOT NULL THEN
            SELECT
                to_recipients,
                cc_recipients,
                bcc_recipients
            INTO
                lv_to_recipients,
                lv_cc_recipients,
                lv_bcc_recipients
            FROM
                alr_distribution_lists
            WHERE
                list_id = lv_list_id
                AND application_id = lv_list_application_id
                AND enabled_flag = 'Y'
                AND end_date_active IS NULL;

        END IF;

        SELECT
            row_count,
            check_id,
            alert_check_id
        INTO
            lv_row_count,
            lv_check_id,
            lv_alert_check_id
        FROM
            alr_action_set_checks
        WHERE
            alert_id = lv_alert_id
            AND alert_check_id = (
                SELECT
                    MAX(alert_check_id)
                FROM
                    alr_action_set_checks
                WHERE
                    alert_id = lv_alert_id
            );
  --  lv_attach_tab.DELETE;

        v_mail_conn := utl_smtp.open_connection(v_mail_host, 25);
        utl_smtp.helo(v_mail_conn, v_mail_host);
        utl_smtp.mail(v_mail_conn, v_from);
        utl_smtp.rcpt(v_mail_conn, v_recipient);
        FOR rec_alert_outputs IN c_get_alert_outputs(lv_alert_id) LOOP
            v_clob := rec_alert_outputs.title
                      || ','
                      || v_clob;
        END LOOP;

        FOR i IN 1..lv_row_count LOOP
            v_clob_lines := empty_clob();
            FOR rec_lines IN c_output_lines(lv_check_id, i) LOOP
                v_clob_lines := rec_lines.value
                                || ','
                                || v_clob_lines;
            END LOOP;

            utl_smtp.data(v_mail_conn, 'Date: '
                                       || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'Dy, DD Mon YYYY hh24:mi:ss')
                                       || crlf
                                       || 'From: '
                                       || v_from
                                       || crlf
                                       || 'Subject: '
                                       || v_subject
                                       || crlf
                                       || 'To: '
                                       || v_recipient
                                       || crlf
                                       || 'MIME-Version: 1.0'
                                       || crlf
                                       ||   -- Use MIME mail standard
                                        'Content-Type: multipart/mixed;'
                                       || crlf
                                       || ' boundary="-----SECBOUND"'
                                       || crlf
                                       || crlf
                                       || '-------SECBOUND'
                                       || crlf
                                       || 'Content-Type: text/plain;'
                                       || crlf
                                       || 'Content-Transfer_Encoding: 7bit'
                                       || crlf
                                       || crlf
                                       || lv_body
                                       || crlf
                                       || crlf
                                       || '-------SECBOUND'
                                       || crlf
                                       || 'Content-Type: text/plain;'
                                       || crlf
                                       || ' name="ASL_Mismatch.csv"'
                                       || crlf
                                       || 'Content-Transfer_Encoding: 8bit'
                                       || crlf
                                       || 'Content-Disposition: attachment;'
                                       || crlf
                                       || ' filename="Mismatch.csv"'
                                       || crlf
                                       || crlf
                                       || v_clob
                                       || crlf
                                       || v_clob_lines
                                       || crlf);

            fnd_file.put_line(fnd_file.output, 'v_clob    ' || v_clob);
            utl_smtp.data(v_mail_conn, v_clob);
            utl_smtp.data(v_mail_conn, v_clob_lines);
 --UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(DBMS_LOB.substr(v_clob_lines, 1, i * 1))) || UTL_TCP.crlf);   
 --UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn,UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(v_clob_lines));        

      --  utl_smtp.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, v_clob_lines);
       -- UTL_SMTP.write_data(v_Mail_Conn, DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(v_clob_lines, 32000, v_index));
            fnd_file.put_line(fnd_file.output, 'v_clob_lines '
                                               || v_clob_lines
                                               || ' Row: '
                                               || i);

        END LOOP;

        utl_smtp.write_data(v_mail_conn, utl_tcp.crlf);
        utl_smtp.write_data(v_mail_conn, '--'
                                         || ' boundary="-----SECBOUND"'
                                         || '--'
                                         || utl_tcp.crlf);

        utl_smtp.close_data(v_mail_conn);
        utl_smtp.quit(v_mail_conn);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            lv_error_msg := p_alert_name
                            || '-'
                            || lv_status
                            || ': '
                            || sqlerrm;
        --debug(pi_message => lv_error_msg
                                    -- );
    END main;

END xx_common_alerts_pkg;
```

Comment: I use [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326026/how-to-export-data-from-log-table-to-email-body-in-oracle/44329605#44329605) for sending mails.  For `crlf` you should better use `utl_tcp.CRLF` I know the mail clients are rather picky if CRLF are wrong or missing.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try to debug your code, I'll share with you my own sendmail function and you can use it to figure out what you're doing wrong. One difference that stands out to me immediately is I'm using base64 encoding rather than 8-bit, to prevent anything in the attachment from messing up SMTP. I'm sure there are multiple ways to do it, but this has been working for me for many years:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sendmail_html(sender_email IN varchar2,
                                          recipient_email IN varchar2,
                                          message_in IN clob,
                                          subject_in IN varchar2 := NULL,
                                          sender_name IN varchar2 :=NULL,
                                          recipient_name IN varchar2 := NULL,
                                          attachment_name_1 IN varchar2 := NULL,
                                          attachment_mime_1 IN varchar2 := NULL,
                                          attachment_clob_1 IN clob := NULL,
                                          attachment_name_2 IN varchar2 := NULL,
                                          attachment_mime_2 IN varchar2 := NULL,
                                          attachment_clob_2 IN clob := NULL,
                                          attachment_name_3 IN varchar2 := NULL,
                                          attachment_mime_3 IN varchar2 := NULL,
                                          attachment_clob_3 IN clob := NULL,
                                          attachment_name_4 IN varchar2 := NULL,
                                          attachment_mime_4 IN varchar2 := NULL,
                                          attachment_clob_4 IN clob := NULL,
                                          attachment_name_5 IN varchar2 := NULL,
                                          attachment_mime_5 IN varchar2 := NULL,
                                          attachment_clob_5 IN clob := NULL)
AS
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  mail_host varchar2(30) := 'localhost';
  mail_connection utl_smtp.connection;
  message clob;
  message_piece varchar2(2000);
  boundary    VARCHAR2(50) := '----=*#abc1234321cba#*=';
  step        PLS_INTEGER  := 12000; -- make sure you set a multiple of 3 not higher than 24573
  var_start_pos integer;
  var_unencoded_raw raw(32767); 
  var_encoded_raw raw(32767);
  var_encoded_string varchar2(32767);
BEGIN
  message := message_in;

  mail_connection := utl_smtp.open_connection(mail_host, 25);
  utl_smtp.helo(mail_connection, mail_host);
  utl_smtp.mail(mail_connection, sender_email);
  utl_smtp.rcpt(mail_connection, recipient_email);
  utl_smtp.open_data(mail_connection);
  utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection,'Date: '||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'dd Mon yy hh24:mi:ss')||utl_tcp.CRLF);
  utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection,'From: '||NVL(sender_name,sender_email)||' <'||sender_email||'>'||utl_tcp.CRLF);
  utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection,'To: '||NVL(recipient_name,recipient_email)||' <'||recipient_email||'>'||utl_tcp.CRLF);
  utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection,'Subject: '||NVL(subject_in,' ')|| utl_tcp.CRLF);
  utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, 'MIME-Version: 1.0' || utl_tcp.CRLF);
  utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="' || boundary || '"' || utl_tcp.CRLF || utl_tcp.CRLF);

  IF dbms_lob.getlength(message) > 0
  THEN
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, '--' || boundary || utl_tcp.CRLF);
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii ' || utl_tcp.CRLF);
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, 'Content-Disposition: inline' || utl_tcp.CRLF || utl_tcp.CRLF);    
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, '<html>'|| utl_tcp.CRLF);
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, '<head>'|| utl_tcp.CRLF);
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, '<title>'||NVL(subject_in,' ')||'</title>'|| utl_tcp.CRLF);
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, '</head>'|| utl_tcp.CRLF); 
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, '<body>'|| utl_tcp.CRLF); 
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, '<pre style="font: monospace">'|| utl_tcp.CRLF); 
    

    FOR chunk IN 1..CEIL(dbms_lob.getlength(message)/1000)
    LOOP
      var_start_pos := 1+(chunk-1)*1000;
      utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection,dbms_lob.substr(message,1000,var_start_pos));      
    END LOOP;
    
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, '</pre>'|| utl_tcp.CRLF);
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, '</body>'|| utl_tcp.CRLF);
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, '</html>'|| utl_tcp.CRLF);
    
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection,utl_tcp.CRLF||utl_tcp.CRLF);   
    
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, '--' || boundary || utl_tcp.CRLF);
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"; format=flowed' || utl_tcp.CRLF);
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, 'Content-Disposition: inline' || utl_tcp.CRLF || utl_tcp.CRLF);

    FOR chunk IN 1..CEIL(dbms_lob.getlength(message)/1000)
    LOOP
      var_start_pos := 1+(chunk-1)*1000;
      utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection,dbms_lob.substr(message,1000,var_start_pos));      
    END LOOP;
    
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection,utl_tcp.CRLF||utl_tcp.CRLF);    
  END IF;
  
  IF LENGTH(attachment_clob_1) > 0
  THEN
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, '--' || boundary || utl_tcp.CRLF);
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, 'Content-Type: ' || attachment_mime_1 || '; name="' || attachment_name_1 || '"' || utl_tcp.CRLF);
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' || utl_tcp.CRLF);    
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' || attachment_name_1 || '"' || utl_tcp.CRLF || utl_tcp.CRLF);
 
    FOR i IN 0 .. TRUNC((dbms_lob.getlength(attachment_clob_1) - 1 )/step)
    LOOP
      var_unencoded_raw := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(dbms_lob.substr(attachment_clob_1, step, i * step + 1));
      var_encoded_raw := utl_encode.base64_encode(var_unencoded_raw);
      var_encoded_string := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(var_encoded_raw);
        
      utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, var_encoded_string);
    END LOOP;

    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, utl_tcp.CRLF || utl_tcp.CRLF);    
  END IF;
  
  IF LENGTH(attachment_clob_2) > 0
  THEN
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, '--' || boundary || utl_tcp.CRLF);
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, 'Content-Type: ' || attachment_mime_2 || '; name="' || attachment_name_2 || '"' || utl_tcp.CRLF);
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' || utl_tcp.CRLF);    
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' || attachment_name_2 || '"' || utl_tcp.CRLF || utl_tcp.CRLF);
 
    FOR i IN 0 .. TRUNC((dbms_lob.getlength(attachment_clob_2) - 1 )/step)
    LOOP
      var_unencoded_raw := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(dbms_lob.substr(attachment_clob_2, step, i * step + 1));
      var_encoded_raw := utl_encode.base64_encode(var_unencoded_raw);
      var_encoded_string := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(var_encoded_raw);
        
      utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, var_encoded_string);
    END LOOP;

    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, utl_tcp.CRLF || utl_tcp.CRLF);    
  END IF;
  
  IF LENGTH(attachment_clob_3) > 0
  THEN
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, '--' || boundary || utl_tcp.CRLF);
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, 'Content-Type: ' || attachment_mime_3 || '; name="' || attachment_name_3 || '"' || utl_tcp.CRLF);
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' || utl_tcp.CRLF);    
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' || attachment_name_3 || '"' || utl_tcp.CRLF || utl_tcp.CRLF);
 
    FOR i IN 0 .. TRUNC((dbms_lob.getlength(attachment_clob_3) - 1 )/step)
    LOOP
      var_unencoded_raw := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(dbms_lob.substr(attachment_clob_3, step, i * step + 1));
      var_encoded_raw := utl_encode.base64_encode(var_unencoded_raw);
      var_encoded_string := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(var_encoded_raw);
        
      utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, var_encoded_string);
    END LOOP;

    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, utl_tcp.CRLF || utl_tcp.CRLF);    
  END IF;
  
  IF LENGTH(attachment_clob_4) > 0
  THEN
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, '--' || boundary || utl_tcp.CRLF);
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, 'Content-Type: ' || attachment_mime_4 || '; name="' || attachment_name_4 || '"' || utl_tcp.CRLF);
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' || utl_tcp.CRLF);    
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' || attachment_name_4 || '"' || utl_tcp.CRLF || utl_tcp.CRLF);
 
    FOR i IN 0 .. TRUNC((dbms_lob.getlength(attachment_clob_4) - 1 )/step)
    LOOP
      var_unencoded_raw := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(dbms_lob.substr(attachment_clob_4, step, i * step + 1));
      var_encoded_raw := utl_encode.base64_encode(var_unencoded_raw);
      var_encoded_string := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(var_encoded_raw);
        
      utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, var_encoded_string);
    END LOOP;

    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, utl_tcp.CRLF || utl_tcp.CRLF);    
  END IF;
    
  IF LENGTH(attachment_clob_5) > 0
  THEN
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, '--' || boundary || utl_tcp.CRLF);
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, 'Content-Type: ' || attachment_mime_5 || '; name="' || attachment_name_5 || '"' || utl_tcp.CRLF);
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' || utl_tcp.CRLF);    
    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' || attachment_name_5 || '"' || utl_tcp.CRLF || utl_tcp.CRLF);
 
    FOR i IN 0 .. TRUNC((dbms_lob.getlength(attachment_clob_5) - 1 )/step)
    LOOP
      var_unencoded_raw := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(dbms_lob.substr(attachment_clob_5, step, i * step + 1));
      var_encoded_raw := utl_encode.base64_encode(var_unencoded_raw);
      var_encoded_string := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(var_encoded_raw);
        
      utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, var_encoded_string);
    END LOOP;

    utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, utl_tcp.CRLF || utl_tcp.CRLF);    
  END IF;
  
  utl_smtp.write_data(mail_connection, '--' || boundary || '--' || utl_tcp.crlf);  
  utl_smtp.close_data(mail_connection);
  utl_smtp.quit(mail_connection);
END;
/
```

This is HTML enabled in the body. I have another one that is plain text. I like having HTML so I can do some simple formatting like bold and italics and such.

My attachments however tend to be text, even if CSV or XML intended for Excel. So, I always use the mime `'text/plain'` for my attachments. Compile your attachment as a CLOB and pass it into one of the attachment parameters.

Comment: Thanks . I have fixed the code and it's working now as expected.