# Send PJ oracle by mail

Tags: oracle

I am unable to retrieve the content of my attachment (an SQL result file created using the spool command).
The attachment is empty even though the corresponding file stored on my server is properly populated.

My procedure:

```
DECLARE
  l_clob CLOB := 'MayBe';
  begin
send_mail_bis_bis(p_to          => 'toto@gmail.com',
          p_from        => 'toto@gmail.com',
          p_subject     => 'result',
          p_text_msg    => 'Maintenant reste la requête à bien la mettre dedans :) ',
          p_attach_name => 'table.csv',
          p_attach_mime => '/home/oracle/pj',
          p_attach_clob => l_clob,
          p_smtp_host   => 'smtp.domaine.fr');
EXCEPTION
WHEN utl_smtp.Transient_Error OR utl_smtp.Permanent_Error then
raise_application_error(-20000, 'Unable to send mail: '||sqlerrm);
 
END;
/
```

Thanks

Attache file an email attachement

Comment: The send_mail_bis_bis function is not an Oracle-supplied function. It was written by someone within your organization or a 3rd party tool, and so folks on this forum are not going to be able to help with it. If you wish to send emails with attachments, that can be done natively by calling utl_smtp procedures, but its rather complex.. you'll have to google up how to do so. I recently posted the function I use. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75273735/unable-to-send-attachment-through-pl-sql-for-multiple-lines-inside-attachment-us/75277722#75277722

Comment: If you want a robust (and supported) email mechanism, install APEX (even if you dont plan to use it to write apps) and then use the APEX_MAIL package to handle all of this easily.  APEX is free to use on any oracle database