# Send excel file stored in directory using utl_smtp

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

Need help in sending excel file as an attachment which is stored in directory of a server.
I have a procedure which writes a file to server and need to send it as as attachement with HTML body message which includes multiple tables and excel attachement. but i am quite stuck in attachment part for now!.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_send_email_with_attach as

file_handle     utl_file.file_type;
output          VARCHAR2(32767);
attachment_text VARCHAR2(32767);
v_dir           VARCHAR2(300) := 'RPT_DIR';
v_recipients    VARCHAR2(2000) := 'abc@gmail.com';
v_sub           VARCHAR2(300) := 'Hello';
v_smtp_server   VARCHAR2(255) := 'mailhost';
conn            utl_smtp.connection;
c_mime_boundary CONSTANT VARCHAR2(256) := 'the boundary can be almost anything';

v_from_name     VARCHAR2(100) := 'xyz@yahoo.com';
BEGIN
file_handle := utl_file.fopen(
                             location  => v_dir,
                             filename  => 'My_First_CSV.CSV',
                             open_mode => 'R'
               );

LOOP
    BEGIN
        utl_file.get_line(
                         file_handle,
                         output
        ); -- we read the file, line by line
        attachment_text := attachment_text || utl_tcp.crlf; --and store every line in 
    the attachment_text variable, separated by a ?new line? character.
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN no_data_found THEN
            EXIT;
    END;
END LOOP;

utl_file.fclose(file_handle);



conn := utl_smtp.open_connection('mailhost');
utl_smtp.helo(conn, 'mailhost');
utl_smtp.mail(conn, v_from_name);
FOR cur_r IN (
    SELECT level AS id, regexp_substr(email_id, '[^;]+', 1, level) AS v_recipient
    FROM
        email_address
    CONNECT BY regexp_substr( email_id, '[^;]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
) LOOP
    utl_smtp.rcpt(conn,cur_r.v_recipient);
END LOOP;

UTL_SMTP.write_data(conn, '--' || c_mime_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.write_data(conn, 'Content-Type: text/plain' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
UTL_SMTP.write_data(
    conn,
    'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' || 'My_First_CSV.CSV' || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf
);


  utl_smtp.open_data(conn);
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    raise_application_error(
                           -20001,
                           'Error: ' || sqlerrm
    );
  END;
```

i beleive i am missing something while writing, kindly help in fixing this. thanks :)

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326026/how-to-export-data-from-log-table-to-email-body-in-oracle/44329605#44329605

Comment: HI @WernfriedDomscheit, suggested code uses RAW datatype, where as i want to send a file which is already existing in directory of server.

Comment: I updated the answer, please have a look