# Using UTL_SMTP to send a large preformatted RFC822 email

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle12c

**EDIT IN CASE IT HELPS SOMEBODY**
Here is my new code, just the changed bits...

```
c := utl_smtp.open_connection(p_mail_host, 25); -- SMTP on port 25
utl_smtp.helo(c, p_mail_host);
utl_smtp.mail(c, p_from);
utl_smtp.rcpt(c, p_to);

select content_blob
into lblob
from FAC_OC_EMAIL_META_DATA
where id = 121;

FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.LOG,'Convert to clob ');
dbms_lob.Createtemporary(lob_loc => message, CACHE => FALSE);

dbms_lob.Converttoclob(dest_lob => message, 
                            src_blob => lblob,
                            amount => dbms_lob.lobmaxsize, dest_offset => l_dest_offsset,
                            src_offset => l_src_offsset, blob_csid => dbms_lob.default_csid,
                            lang_context => l_lang_context, warning => l_warning);

  -- Mail Body
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.LOG,'Write body ');    
    LobLen := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(Message);
    LOOP
        EXIT WHEN OFFSET > LobLen;
        DBMS_LOB.READ(Message, amount, OFFSET, BUFFER);
        --UTL_SMTP.WRITE_RAW_DATA(l_mail_conn, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(BUFFER));
        UTL_SMTP.DATA(c, BUFFER);
        OFFSET := OFFSET + amount;
    END LOOP;   
utl_smtp.quit(c);
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**
I am having to change course a bit on a project and wondering if I can rescue the situation with UTL_SMTP.
I have tested code which use javax.mail to format my message in parts, including pictures and attachments. The problem is that we cannot actually transport the message. I am saving the entire RFC 822 message before sending to a table as a blob, so wondering whether I can use UTL_SMTP to send it **from what I have saved to the table** instead.

My code reads from the table where the RFC822 email is stored and succesfully sends a message, but it looks like this. It literally sends the entire text.
Is what I'm doing possible, or do I need to start again composing my body in UTL_SMTP with parts for the attachments, parts for the images... ?

[image]

I would like this simple example message to just say "test body".
I know why the subject and dates are not there, I'm more worried about the body. I am hoping that I have left out something simple...

I have chosen a very simple email to show you, but they can get very big. This is my blob.

```
Message-ID: <506905983.1683798456189.JavaMail.javamailuser@localhost>
Date: Thu, 11 May 2023 10:47:36 +0100 (BST)
From: CAB@test.com
To: TEST@test.com
Subject: Test Email 14:41 [REF:]
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
    boundary="----=_Part_0_-1663355530.1683798455997"
------=_Part_0_-1663355530.1683798455997
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
<p>test body</p>
------=_Part_0_-1663355530.1683798455997--
```

This is my code.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE barry_test_proc (
    p_errbuf  OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2,
    p_retcode OUT NOCOPY NUMBER
) AS 

p_mail_host varchar2(1000) := 'xyz.local';
p_from varchar2(1000) := '1@test.com';
p_to varchar2(1000) := '2@test.com';
l_mail_conn utl_smtp.connection;


--Message handling
lblob blob;
l_warning      INTEGER;
message clob;
OFFSET INTEGER := 1;
LobLen INTEGER;
amount INTEGER := 8000;
BUFFER VARCHAR2(32000);
l_dest_offsset INTEGER := 1;
l_src_offsset  INTEGER := 1;
l_lang_context INTEGER := dbms_lob.default_lang_ctx;

BEGIN

FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.LOG,'Called ');

FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.LOG,'Opening Connection ');
l_mail_conn := utl_smtp.open_connection(p_mail_host, 25);

FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.LOG,'Helo ');

utl_smtp.helo(l_mail_conn, p_mail_host);

utl_smtp.mail(l_mail_conn, p_from);
utl_smtp.rcpt(l_mail_conn, p_to);

FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.LOG,'Opening Data ');
utl_smtp.open_data(l_mail_conn);

--(add subject code later)

FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.LOG,'Fetch message for writing ');
select content_blob
into lblob
from FAC_OC_EMAIL_META_DATA
where id = 121;

FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.LOG,'Convert to clob ');
dbms_lob.Createtemporary(lob_loc => message, CACHE => FALSE);

dbms_lob.Converttoclob(dest_lob => message, 
                            src_blob => lblob,
                            amount => dbms_lob.lobmaxsize, dest_offset => l_dest_offsset,
                            src_offset => l_src_offsset, blob_csid => dbms_lob.default_csid,
                            lang_context => l_lang_context, warning => l_warning);

  -- Mail Body
    FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.LOG,'Write body ');    
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    LobLen := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(Message);
    LOOP
        EXIT WHEN OFFSET > LobLen;
        DBMS_LOB.READ(Message, amount, OFFSET, BUFFER);
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_RAW_DATA(l_mail_conn, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(BUFFER));
        OFFSET := OFFSET + amount;
    END LOOP;   
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    /*IF NOT isHTML THEN
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, UTL_TCP.CRLF || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, Footer);
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(con, UTL_TCP.CRLF);
    END IF;*/

FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.LOG,'Closing ');
utl_smtp.close_data(l_mail_conn);

FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.LOG,'Quiting ');
utl_smtp.quit(l_mail_conn);

FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.LOG,'Finished ');
 
END;
```

Thanks

Comment: Compare your code with my one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326026/how-to-export-data-from-log-table-to-email-body-in-oracle/44329605#44329605 (perhaps you did already). Maybe you have to work only with `UTL_SMTP.WRITE_RAW_DATA()` or you need `UTL_TCP` to go even a level lower.

Comment: Yes I completely took your code that writes "raw" from a clob earlier :)   I don't understand the difference between writing these lines one by one with UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA, compared to writing from a LOB (with your code thank you) which has all of that in already. I will in the meantime have a look at UTL_TCP

Comment: Cracked it. Essentially just a one line change. I'm using UTL_SMTP.DATA(c, BUFFER); now. Will edit the original post. Thanks @WernfriedDomscheit and https://www.dba-oracle.com/t_utl_smtp_utility.htm

Comment: OT: it is imho better to use localhost as SMTP server. Handover your mail to your local sendmail/postfix. Then check /var/log/maillog and you will see what happened to your mail. Whether it was accepted by smart relay host, why it was rejected. In /var/spoo/mail you can find your mail if it is reject. Using local SMTP is much better from troubleshooting procedure.