# How can I set up automated email notifications for failed procedures in Oracle SQL Dev using SMTP?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm looking to generate an automated email for when a procedure fails. I do have SMTP to generate the emails. However, I have had no luck. Any help would be great. I have tried using this website as a resource for reference: https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/scheduler-enhancements-11gr2

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44326026/how-to-export-data-from-log-table-to-email-body-in-oracle/44329605#44329605